# C# Post XML file using RestSharp

Tags: c#, http-post, restsharp, rest-client

I have written a method to post messages to an uri.

```
public string RestClientPost(string uri, string message = null)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(uri);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            request.AddParameter(message, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var result = "";
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            result = response.Content;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

and below code is used above method to post.

```
public void test123()
    {
        string uri = "myuri"; //private uri, cannot expose.
        var file= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Settings.EnvValPath, "RestClientXML", "test.XML"));
        var content = new RestClientServices().RestClientPost(uri, file);

    }
```

however, it returns "Unsupported Media type".

my test.XML's content is

```
<customer> 
    <customerName>test</customerName > 
    <customerStatus>OK</customerStatus > 
</customer>
```

And using Advanced Rest Client Plugin for Google Chrome, I'm able to post it and return with string that I wanted. Is there something wrong?? I set "content-type" to "text/xml" in Advanced Rest Client.

- The return message is id of the customer. e.g: 2132

Comment: I change my original plan from RestSharp to Rest Client C# which I can get what I want now. If you guys need the answers, just drop me a message.

Answer (score 1):

im using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps),

[image: postman get the c# code tools]

if you can call any xml web services with this tools , then you can click on [code](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/#___gatsby) and select restsharp and copy paste it to your code

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the header "Accept" is to specify a type of return object. In this case a value of a variable **content**, not the type of content to send. Specify a type of content to send with: "Content-Type: application/xml".

If a return type of POST request is a media file, you can use 'image/png' or 'image/jpeg'. You can use multiple accept header values like: "*application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, and image/png*".
For example, you can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to debug HTTP(s) traffic - it's a good tool for web developers.

Comment: The return value is a string. E.g: 2312. Can you show an example? I don't really understand your answer.

Comment: What @Joseph wanted to say is that 'Accept' header indicates the type of response that you expect (see [Accept Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). So in this specific case you don't need it

You should specify request format: 
`request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml`